# how to edit Javascript in Html in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

We can edit and execute JavaScript code from the *.js file in the Sources panel of Chrome DevTools. However, if the js code comes from the *.html file, how can we edit and execute them besides adding breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome Dev Tools you can setup a 'workspace' and when you make changes to a file it will save locally and also show changes in the browser.

Please follow this Google guide on setting it up. It's easy to follow and with screenshots, if you need further help then please message back.

Link with instructions: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow

Comment: My project is developed in .net,so there are no *.html files in source code directory,only *.cshtml files. 
I have tried your measure,it workes well if there are *.html files.
Thank you anyway.